# java replaceall cuts everything of after last substring

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string called msg:

```
A64=20170210^A117=ABCDEF^A192=53012519.72^A193
```

I want to replace everything between `A117=` and `^` with `GHIJK`.

I want this;

```
A64=20170210^A117=GHIJK^A192=53012519.72^A193
```

I tried:

```
msg=msg.replaceAll("A117=[^&]*\\^","A117="+"GHIJK"+"^");
```

However it returns this:

```
A64=20170210^A117=GHIJK^A
```

Why has the rest of the string disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are matching greedy (which is the default behavior). Since there is another `^` in your string, `[^&]*\\^` will consume everything (including `^`s) until it doesn't find another `^`. You can turn off the greedy behavior by appending a question mark to your `*`: `[^&]*?`. If you use this, it won't match greedy but is going to be happy with the first following `^` it's going to find.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `A117=[^\\^]*`

`A117=[^\\^]*` : match `A117=`

`[^\\^]*` match everything until `^` character

```
    System.out.println("A64=20170210^A117=ABCDEF^A192=53012519.72^A193"
        .replaceAll("A117=[^\\^]*", "A117=GHIJK"));
```

Output

```
A64=20170210^A117=GHIJK^A192=53012519.72^A193
```

Demo

```js
const regex = /A117=[^\^]*/g;
const str = `A64=20170210^A117=ABCDEF^A192=53012519.72^A193`;
const subst = `A117=GHIJK`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rest of the characters disappeared because of the condition `[^&]*` which basically searches until it finds `&` character.

You can use this also:

```
msg=msg.replaceAll("A117=.*?\\^", "A117="+"GHIJK"+"^");
```